# IdentityHashMap gets NPE when trying to put

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, eclipselink, identity

I'm using `EclipseLink 2.6.0-M3` apparently when trying to query and call getResult().

I get this exception that looks weird (EclipseLink code looks safe from NPE) and main suspect is the JDK:

```
    **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:447)**
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkChangeSet.addObjectChangeSet(UnitOfWorkChangeSet.java:160)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkChangeSet.mergeUnitOfWorkChangeSet(UnitOfWorkChangeSet.java:510)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:469)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(QueryImpl.java:963)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:207

)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:461)

Using this Java version (IBM JDK) - 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxi3270sr9fp20-20151106_01(SR9 FP20))
```

It happens rarely, so debug won't help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe use a debugger and inspect what you are trying to put in there ?

Comment: I'll edit my post, it happens rarely.

Comment: You'll have to hit IBM support.  The line doesn't match up to the IdentityHashMap source I have, but seems like a multi core optimization causing an object to be used before it is initialized.  Such as if Object[] tab = table; occurs after the tab.length; call.  Do you have the ability to change the JDK being used to Oracle's or try a later IBM JDK?

Comment: I already tried Oracle JDK and failed to reproduce it, again, that's very seldom, defintly I'm goint to hit IBM support @Chris